# Would Halfling Nimbleness allow a halfling to squeeze past a gelatinous cube without being engulfed?

Tags: dnd-5e, halfling

Would a halfling be able to squeeze past a [gelatinous cube](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gelatinous-cube) (which it states it takes up its entire space) in a 10' high and wide corridor with its [Halfling Nimbleness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/halfling#HalflingTraits) trait? Or would the poor halfling be engulfed as it tried to dive past it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The halfling will have to save versus Engulf

Per the Ooze's Engulf ability, other creatures can enter the space, but any that do are subject to the ability and must save at Disadvantage. This applies regardless of creature size since it's a specific beats general situation in the rules.

Halfling Nimbleness doesn't negate this. That feature's benefit relates primarily to permitting them to move through the space of an enemy who is only 1 size larger than themselves (as opposed to 2 sizes for everyone else). So were this not a gelatinous cube and instead an enemy human guard, the halfling could move through the guard's space, but an elf ally could not because the enemy is the same size as them.

It's worth noting that moving through an enemy's space is difficult terrain, so a Halfling without improvements to its speed will need to Dash to fully move through the cube's space.

Comment: So they can move through it, but they may be engulfed? As opposed to other creatures that simply can't move through it?

Comment: It's a niche case where everyone can actually move through it because the ability says they can. I've edited the answer to clarify that it's unique.

Comment: Yep. Normally, creatures can't move through enemies' spaces unless two sizes larger or smaller. The gelatinous cube's "Ooze Cube" trait specifically makes an exception to this general rule that would normally prevent typical enemies from moving through its space: "The cube takes up its entire space. Other creatures can enter the space, but a creature that does so is subjected to the cube's Engulf and has disadvantage on the saving throw." As Pyrotechnical stated, the Halfling Nimbleness trait simply allows them to move through the cube's space (which the cube's trait lets them do anyway).

Comment: @V2Blast This would be a great addition to this answer or an answer in itself!

Comment: @NautArch: Thanks! I'm mostly reiterating what Pyrotechnical already said, though he's(?) welcome to edit the contents of my comment into his answer.